# Wildcard DNS only working selectively

Tags: apache, dns, bind

I'm trying to setup my own DNS server to be able to customize it. Now, I have it working (for the most part) by having a record of

```
*.technolobuzz.tk.          IN  A   184.153.205.110
```

That works when I do "www." or even a random "no.", but if I try to do "blog." in my web browser, I get server not found. So, I don't know what I'm doing wrong to have only certain domains work. (I'm doing this so I can use Wordpress multisite, and .TK doesn't offer wildcards.)

Comment: I believe you've solved the problem somehow, as the record returns properly when I try it.  Note that it'd be better to have more than one nameserver, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The format you are using is correct, however have you upated the serial number of the record you have set?

```
example.com. 86400     IN      SOA     example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>             2005100804      ; Serial YYYYMMDDXX
                                    10800           ; Refresh
                                    3600            ; Retry
                                    3600000         ; Expire
                                    86400 )         ; minimum
                        IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
                        IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
                        IN      MX      10      mail.example.com.
                        IN      A       192.168.1.1
mail                    IN      A       192.168.1.1
ns1                     IN      A       192.168.1.1
ns2                     IN      A       10.0.0.2
*.example.com.          IN      A       192.168.1.1
```

Every time you update your record you need to also update the serial number so tha the changes are propogated out (ie after the TTL expires it knows the record has changed).

Comment: I tried changing my serial from 1394120808 to 2012071723. Still no change. Even if I ping it, I get no response (unknown host).

Comment: Remember after you update the serial it still takes time for the change to propogate (the refresh value, AKA TTL). You can force windows to dump you cache with ipconfig /flushdns but that doesn't stop your upstream providers caching it. Also don't ping, use nslookup or dig

Comment: Okay. I think it just needed to propagate. I set my DNS on my computer to my IP address. Now, everything works but the site without a prefix (e.g.. example.com vs www.example.com).